# Change account type to Company in google appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, billing

I have a Google Appengine application that, in the Billing Profile section has 'Particular' (or something along the lines) set as the account type. It was set like that when the billing was enabled. Now the billing is going to be handled by a company, so I need to change that option and set it as a company, but when I click edit there's no option to change it. Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks.

EDIT: I ended up contacting them through a support ticket. It was solved within the hour.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add someone from the company to be a billing administrator and then that person will be able to change the credit card info or anything else regarding the billing settings.

Before doing anything invite the person you want to be responsible for the payments to the app from the **Permissions** page.

If you are the owner of the app and you are the one who actually enabled billing at one point you will have access to the **Billing Status** > **Manage Billing Administrators**. From there you'll be able to assign more people to become billing administrators.

After making the desired person a billing administrator, then that person will be able to change from the **Billing Settings** the payment method and start using the company's credit card or whatever else is associated with payments.

Comment: I've already done that. What I need is to change that particular setting. The new organization is very picky about this stuff, and the tax ID number needs to appear in the invoices.